# Is `housing finance’s future remains murky` a Object Clause in the sentence?

Tags: clauses

There is a long sentence.

> And contradictory messages from Trump himself about his priorities mean housing finance’s future remains murky.

Can i shorten it as the below?

1. `Messages`  mean that housing finance’s future remains murky.
2. `from Trump himself about his priorities` is a attribute to modify `Messages`.
3. `housing finance’s future remains murky` is a Object Clause？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct in your interpretation.  The root sentence "A means B" can be broken up as follows:

> And [contradictory] messages [from Trump himself] [about his priorities] mean [housing finance's future remains murky].

Both "from Trump himself" and "about his priorities" are adjective clauses that modify "messages" (A)

"housing finance's future remains murky" is the object clause (B)

By the way, this sentence is not especially long.  Here's one that's somewhat longer:

> Scientists from the Austrian Society of Innovative Computer Sciences hope their craft, named the ASV Roboat, will cover 150 nautical miles (172 miles) and work for 100 hours without human intervention once it is put into the water July 9.

The root here is "[some kind of] scientists hope [something will happen]"  The object clause is everything that comes after "hope", and which you can break down separately if it's unclear.